# Is there a way to avoid SIFT extracting the same point multiple times?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I noticed that, using openCV, SIFT extracts many times the same points on the image, and gives them different descriptors.
Is there a way to avoid this, and have unique keypoints?

Comment: If the descriptors differ, they are probably not the same point. Possibly at different scales.

Comment: it only does that if the point could have multiple orientations (see SIFT paper). in that case, you'd want this behavior. if you only care about the points, not the descriptors, you can just "detect"  instead of "detect and compute".